# How to Retain python dictionary value

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to create a dictionary from below list, I need only 2 values and I want them as key and value. It is only printing the last dict value from list and missing 'key':'earthquake'

```
{'locale': 'Raj', 'latlng': 'Sahu', 'include': 'website', 'agent': 'Pramod'}
```

I expect it to print

```
{'locale': 'Raj', 'latlng': 'Sahu', 'include': 'website', 'agent': 'Pramod', 'key':'earthquake'}
```

What am I missing here?

```
parameters = [
                    {
                        "type": "0",
                        "name": "key",
                        "value": "earthquake"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "0",
                        "name": "include",
                        "value": "website"
                    }
                ]
    def create():
        for parameter in parameters:
            params = {parameter.get('name'):parameter.get('value')}
        params["locale"] = "Raj"
        params["agent"] = "Pramod"
        params["latlng"] = "Sahu"
        print params
        return params

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        create()
```

Answer (score 2):

You are replacing your dict in each loop iteration. Try putting your declaration above the for loop then adding the key and value to it on each iteration like so

```
params = {}
for parameter in parameters:
    param[parameter.get('name')] = parameter.get('value')
params['locale'] = 'raj'
# ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You're iterating over the list of dictionaries. So on the second pass it sets the key to `include` and the value to `website`. You need to initialize a dictionary above the loop where results will be stored otherwise you will keep overwriting it. You can also do this:

```
params = {}
params["locale"] = "Raj"
params["agent"] = "Pramod"
params["latlng"] = "Sahu"

for parameter in parameters:
    params.update({parameter.get('name'):parameter.get('value')})
```

Answer (score 0):

using comprehension, you could do:

```
params = { p.get('name'):p.get('value') for p in parameters if p.get('value') == 'earthquake' }
params['locale'] = 'raj'
# ...
```